# Seat clamp slid the seat down as I was riding, hurt my knees

Tags: seatpost, injury

So I was riding a community shared bicycle that many city's have that you can ride around for a small fee. While I was riding it, the seat clamp must have been loose and the seat was sliding down lowering as I was riding. I did not notice this right away until the seat eventually bottomed out.

After this happened, my knees hurt, and my right knee feels unstable when I squat down to pick something up or sit in a chair.

Could this have caused a knee injury? What forces would have affected my knees if the seat was lowering as I was cycling?

Comment: Yes, riding with the seat too low is a common cause of knee injuries.  The knee is not "designed" to absorb repeated large forces at a "tight" angle.  (Presumably your injury will resolve in a few days, but if it's not better after 2 weeks you should see an ortho, or at least a physical therapist.)

Comment: If it helps I'm a big boy > 290 Pounds so it can't be too good for my knees

Comment: It's not good for anyone, but your weight probably has more to do with the sliding of the clamp than your sensitivity to the low seat.  The sensitivity has to do more with your general physical condition and simply the nature of your joints.

Comment: (In general, for road and casual riding, one should position the bike seat as high as possible without forcing you to "rock" in the seat to maintain pedal contact.  Your knees should be *nearly* (but not completely) straight at the bottom of the pedal stroke.)  (A slightly lower seat position is sometimes preferred for off-road biking, however.)

Comment: One issue with these bikes is that they're (at least the ones I've ridden) not really designed to make it easy to unweight the saddle for potholes etc., and the resulting shock is what moves the saddle. Driver behaviour where these sluggish bikes are typically ridden doesn't make dodging potholes easy either. The frequently-adjusted QR also works loose so I normally tighten them when I hire one and sometimes put the saddle back up at traffic lights (and I'm around 2/3 the OP's weight)

Comment: Whatever problem you have wasn't caused by the seat moving _per se_. It may have been caused by cycling with the saddle too low, or it may have just been caused by cycling, period, if that's not something you normally do.

Comment: I get knee ache after a climb on some bikes - it's because you're using muscles in a different way to normal - also known as exercise.   Give it a couple of days of rest, and if you ride those bikes again then check the clamp before hiring it.

Comment: You would do better to edit any (reasonably relevant) supplementary information (like your weight) into the question rather than in a comment.